# Android SDK Manager won't start/open

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager

I know this is a common problem, and I have tried several solutions and none of them work for me.

I have deleted everything and started over. Could someone try to help me to get this to work?

I have these folders:
*C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702

C:\Android\android-ndk-r8e

C:\Android\android-sdk-windows

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

C:\Program Files\Java\jre8*

When trying to run android.bat:

```
C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>android.bat
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: SWT folder 'lib\x86_64' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

Comment: What is the error when you try to open SDK Manager?

Comment: I have installed the jdk1.7 now *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android currently support up to Java 7 (JDK 1.7). If you use JDK 1.8, it won't work.

Also, assuming you're using Java 7, set up `JAVA_HOME` in Environment Variables by pointing it to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71** so the Android SDK Manager knows which Java version to use.

On Windows 64-bit, Environment Variables can be accessed by going to **Start | Control Panel | System | Advanced System Settings | System Properties | Advance | Environment Variables** option. *Note: You may need to restart Windows for the changes to take effect.*

CAVEAT: On **Windows 8.1**, if the above steps fail, then install the Android SDK from the **installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe** executable which can be downloaded from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Also, ensure that you uninstall JDK 1.8 from Windows 8.1 and only use JDK 1.7 with Android SDK Manager (or 1.6 if you need it).

Comment: I have Installed jdk1.7 now, and changed the JAVA_HOME variable in "My Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables." to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67". But it's still not working. I don't know if im using Java 7 or 8, how do I make sure of using Java 7?

Comment: Did you set the `JAVA_HOME` variable under the **System Variables** section? You may need to restart Windows for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I just it in both "System Variables" and "User variables for $NAME"

Comment: You don't need to set it up in the **User Variables** section.

Comment: Alright, I deleted it again. But do you know whats wrong with my setup? I have the output from running "C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat" in the question, maybe that holds some information?

Comment: The error message is referring to the missing **swt.jar** found under the Android SDK directory, namely ../android-sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/ directory. Maybe you haven't install or unpack the Android SDK properly.

Comment: I have the file there :/ and it uses 1620kb, which seems about right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61631/discussion-between-chuongpham-and-jeggy).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is still a problem with your environment variable *Path*, could you check that there is a URL to your java 1.7 bin path? e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin

You could also try from suggested here https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136334/xcopy-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command:

Add this to your path variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if the ANDROID_SWT environment variable is pointing to a correct folder (i.e. sdk\tools\lib\x86 in your adt folder).