# Android.bat won't start. Sdk Manager won't run

Tags: java, android, windows, batch-file, android-sdk-manager

It's about the sdk tools and that the manager just won't start no matter what I tried.
Things I already tried:

[Android SDK manager won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open)

[Can't get Android SDK Manager to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504325/cant-get-android-sdk-manager-to-open)

i read about to change Environment Variables, what are those exactly? here:
[Android SDK Manager won't start/open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960924/android-sdk-manager-wont-start-open)

my computer runs windows 10.
my paths:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
```

tools folder is on the destop.
neither andriod.bat or sdkmanger.bat open something, only a cmd window for a brief second then it close.

Comment: post your code for the 2 bat files

Comment: i just deletet it everything and downloaded fresh, i found something interesting here which is fresh: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-android-command-deprecated-error-unable-to-list-target-platforms.458814/

Comment: FINALLY IT WOKRED , downgrading worked, can be closed